# "Assigning" public IP to machine on LAN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, windows-server-2016

So I recently started playing with Windows Server, been working great so far, then I basically hit a brick wall when I attempted to set up a VPN.

In simplest terms, I have 4 public IP addresses that I purchased from my ISP, and I'd like to assign one of those addresses wholly to the Windows Server machine.

I've tried DNS Forwarding, creating a Proxy ARP and creating a 1:1 NAT rule my firewall, and I've tried just straight out port forwarding but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My router is running pfSense.

Any leads would come in handy, thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you connected to your ISP so that it can give you four public IPs? Whatever you use to connect to it, you need to configure that machine. How does the ISP side show up on that machine?

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't really answer mine. We have a machine running pfSense that is connected to the ISP-issued modem. The IPs are usable IPs, I am not sure how the ISP set it up, but I was able to get it to make it so that it takes you to the pfsense web interface. When I try to port forward it to a different machine however, even specifying the address, it won't work, it'll just go to the gateway regardless. I can't just use the WAN interface either since the address assigned to it by pfSense is different from the one I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, depending on how the ISP has set up your connection.

1. You assign the public address to the router, DNAT (port-forward) all relevant ports to the server's regular LAN address, and likewise SNAT all outgoing connections. (In pfSense, "1:1 NAT" covers both at once.) This works regardless of what the ISP expects, but of course you're still behind NAT. Proxy-ARP isn't used, because no "proxying" is happening: the router already generates legitimate ARP replies in this setup.
2. You assign the public address directly to your server, then add a link route on your router (with the address as destination, LAN as interface, and no gateway). NAT is not needed. *Note: I'm afraid pfSense does not support adding link routes via webUI, or at least makes it painfully non-obvious.*

   - If the ISP *expects* this address to be "on-link", i.e. directly assigned to the router, you must also enable proxy-ARP on the router (making the ISP *think* it's still on-link).
   - If the ISP has routed the address via another of your addresses, proxy-ARP isn't needed.
   - If the WAN connection is "point-to-point" (such as PPPoE), proxy-ARP is not needed either, because there *is* no ARP in that type of connection.

In all cases, "DNS forwarding" is the completely wrong tool. (In pfSense, "DNS forwarder" is basically an older variant of the "DNS resolver" function – the latter uses Unbound, and the former uses dnsmasq.)

---

How do you find out what the ISP expects (assuming the WAN connection is like Ethernet, and not point-to-point)?

- First the router needs to have a "packet capture" (or "packet sniffer") function – such as `tcpdump`. You'll also need a way to ping or otherwise contact the address from an *external* system (various public "looking glass" websites should work). Also, make sure the router *doesn't* have the address assigned, and that it *doesn't* have proxy-ARP active.
- While the external system is sending packets to the address, check what your router sees. If there are ARP requests coming from the ISP for this address, then it's expected to be "on-link" (and this is where the proxy-ARP requirement comes from). If there aren't any, and the real packets simply arrive with your router's MAC in the header, then the IP address is separately routed.
- Again, this doesn't apply to PPP / PPPoE: that type of connection doesn't use ARP at all (and therefore doesn't need proxy-ARP); packets will simply arrive through the tunnel anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you get 4 usable IPs?

As in 4 IPs, plus one IP for broadcasting and one IP for network ID.  So 6 in total?

Or did you get 4 IPs, say 4.3.2.0, 4.3.2.1, 4.3.2.2, 4.3.2.3

I am guessing the latter, in the latter case:

- 4.3.2.0 is your network ID and not really useable.
- 4.3.2.1 would typically be the IP of your gateway (e.g. the internal IP of your modem)
- 4.3.2.2 would be the only IP you have for free usage (as on, assign this to your sole computer).
- 4.3.2.3 would be the broadcast address.

If I am wrong please mention the setup in your post. Do not include the litertal IPs, feel free to write your IPS you got as aaa.bbb.132.32-5/252.

If you intend to use both NAT and normal IP addressing, also mention that.

<sup>Now if I only could use markup in comments then this would be posted as a comment rather than a guess at what the setup is.</sup>

Comment: This is only correct if it's configured as an on-link subnet; there are other routing possibilities in which "network ID" and "broadcast address" do not apply at all.

Comment: Yes. I am guessing here. We really do not have enough information. Temped to ask for it as a comment and trying to be helpful to the OP. But once the OP answers it may very well be wrong. In which case I'll delete it.

Comment: Yeah, our ISP told us they are 4 usable IPs, I tested it using port forwarding and it worked fine, but I want to know how to assign one of them to a specific machine wholly.

Comment: uhm. Just assign them? It should just work.  No need to set up PAT, NAT, port forwarding or anything. Just assign IPs to your desktops and one of the four to the firewall (or whatever SOHO 'router' you use) to be used as gateway.